# sharepoint list web service updatelistitem caml

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Can I update a sharepoint list item using list webservice updatelistitem method's field title instead of field Id.
for eg: msdn sample uses Field Name ID
batchElement.InnerXml = "" +
   "6" +
   "Modified sixth item" +
   "7" +
   "Modified seventh item" +
   "5" +
   "" +
   "Added item"

Since I am pulling the information from sql db to update the list and I dont know the item id, can i use title as condition to update the other item fields?

- Gane

Answer (score 0):

Are you querying gthe sharepoint database when you say " I am pulling the information from sql db"? If so don't. If not and you are using an external db in which you store an item's title, you probably need to do a call to the same service's GetListItems method, using a query the returns items based on the Title field. The query would be something like so:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name='Title' />
      <Value Type='Text'>Title of item</Value>
    </Eq>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

or, if you need more, nest the Eq elements in OR's like so

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <Or>
      <Or>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Title' />
          <Value Type='Text'>Title of item</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Title' />
          <Value Type='Text'>Other Title of item</Value>
        </Eq>
      </Or>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Title' />
        <Value Type='Text'>Yet another Title of item</Value>
      </Eq>
    </Or>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

Then use the ID's in the result of this call to build your batch xml.

Comment: I am getting information from an external db. I was wondering can I do a web service batch update a sharepoint list using title, instead of ID. Otherwise I need to query the list using your method above to get the ID for the title or so.